# WSO2 Governance Registry and changing server types

Tags: wso2

We are looking at the WSO2 Governance Registry tool to help us in enforcing governance - specifically v5.0 (and the dependency graphing is awesome).  When using the publisher to add a server, one of the elements to capture is the type of server.

Currently it lists the WSO2 server types and 'Generic Server'.  I would like to extend the list of server types to reflect what is being used here.

I managed to find the location of the server configuration using the Carbon browser and have added the types.

However, the Publisher still shows the original list.  But when I view a specific server's details in the Carbon browser, I can see the values I've added and I can edit a server's details to reflect the applicable type.

However, the moment I view the server details in the Publisher it shows the updated value, but on editing the field, only the original drop down list without my changes are shown.

Is the publisher's list of server types stored in a different location?  I edited the list found here:

> system/config/repository/components/org…governance/configuration/server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify "server" RXT configuration,  You have to edit the "server" RXT configuration located under "Artifact Types"[1].

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance500/Deploying+an+Extension+File

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for.  Just to add, one has to restart the Governance Registry tool for the Publisher to pick up the changes when adding an entry - it did show the new values though on previously captured servers.